# How can I push tensors to a TensorFlow queue and pull them from another process?

Tags: queue, tensorflow

I have a TensorFlow cluster up and running, and I'm trying to enqueue data using one client process and dequeue it from another process. I can't get this to work, what am I doing wrong?

Here's my program to push data:

```
# queue_push.py
import tensorflow as tf
import time

with tf.container("qtest"):
    q = tf.FIFOQueue(capacity=10, dtypes=[tf.float32],
                     shapes=[[]], name="q")
    v = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=())
    enqueue = q.enqueue([v])

with tf.Session("grpc://localhost:2210") as sess:
    while True:
        t = time.time()
        print(t)
        sess.run(enqueue, feed_dict={v: t})
        time.sleep(1)
```

And my program to pull data:

```
# queue_pull.py
import tensorflow as tf
import time

with tf.container("qtest"):
    q = tf.FIFOQueue(capacity=10, dtypes=[tf.float32],
                     shapes=[[]], name="q")
    dequeue = q.dequeue()

with tf.Session("grpc://localhost:2222") as sess:
    while True:
        v = sess.run(dequeue)
        print("Pulled:", v)
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

When I run them, here's what I get:

```
$ python queue_push.py
1472420887.974484
1472420888.991067
1472420889.995756
1472420890.998365
1472420892.001799
1472420893.008567
1472420894.011109
1472420895.014532
1472420896.02017
1472420897.024806
1472420898.03187
(then blocked forever)
```

And in parallel:

```
$ python queue_pull.py
(blocked forever)
```

Comment: Love your code, man! Finally: The enqueue must be run inside session.run(...)!! ARGH! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To share a [`tf.FIFOQueue`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#FIFOQueue) (or other TensorFlow queue) between multiple sessions, you need to pass the optional `shared_name` argument to the [constructor](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#FIFOQueue.__init__), and set it to the same string in each instance. For example, you could create `q` as follows in the two scripts:

```
q = tf.FIFOQueue(capacity=10, dtypes=[tf.float32], shapes=[[]],
                 shared_name="shared_q", name="q")
```

The `shared_name` does not have to be the same as the `name` for the queue, but it does need to be unique among all other queues created in the same container on the same device. You can share queues without using a [`with tf.container():`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/framework.html#Graph.container) block; the `tf.container()` block provides a way of grouping stateful objects so that they can be cleared selectively (using [`tf.Session.reset()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/client.html#Session.reset)).

---

**N.B.** The default sharing behavior is different for [`tf.Variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Variable) objects, which are **shared by default** based on their `name` property. Otherwise, all shared objects (queues, readers, etc.) in TensorFlow graphs are only shared when you set the `shared_name` argument in their constructors.

Comment: Awesome, once again! Your SO answers are a goldmine. Do you have a bitcoin address so I can offer you a drink? :)

Comment: Glad to help! I don't have a bitcoin address, but the plaudits are more than rewarding enough :).